# angular 6 service url best practices

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am using below service and service url. i coded these type of services in my test project. but these url can access and changing using postman.

```
export class ArdService {

     private ardurl = 'http://126.160.101.92/my-test/getArDataServiceBetween?';
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


      getArdReceiptHeader(fromDate: string,toDate: string) :Observable<any>{
        console.log(fromDate);console.log(toDate);
        return this.http.get(`${this.ardurl}`+`startDate=`+`${fromDate}`+`&endDate=`+`${toDate}`);

      }
```

what this the best,secured way to write these type of services .
Thanks

Comment: send token with  API call so the server can validate incoming request based on token